# SQL query to create a list of values to use in a drop down list

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Relative newbie to SQL here and I need help writing a query.
We use an application that uses SAP Crystal reports as it's reporting tool.  In the application users are able to select the run parameters for the report, and these parameters are then passed to the report and inserted into the SQL query used to create the report.
For some reports we want to let the users decide how they want to group the reports using 3 options (Account, Manager and Broker) rather than having 3 versions of the report.
To avoid typing errors, I would to provide the 3 options as a list, which would appear in a drop down.  Is there a way to do this in a query without creating records in a table?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a parameter and enter the 3 values in the list of default values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a web page explaining the process step-by-step: https://www.rklesolutions.com/blog/crystal-reports-p4

Comment: Thanks for this link.  Sorry, I should have been clearer.  The front end application provides the parameter screen and passes the parameters to the Crystal report file, so I want to create a query in the front end application in sql.  Currently I can use a query in the front end to pull a list of unique account numbers for example, and present this list in a drop down.  I would like to do the same thing, but hopefully not by pulling data from the database.  I hope this makes for sense.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you simply need to populate a dropDown control with a list of static values.  But you didn't mention your programming language. Assuming this is C#:

```
ListItem item = new ListItem(itemText, itemValue);
dropdownlist.Items.Add(item);
```